# Styling for multi tenant rails api apps

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multi-tenant, sprockets, stylus, rails-api

I have a rails-api app where I'd like to serve a stylus stylesheet with some variables set based on the current tenant.

The main app itself is a static, standalone RIA built in Dojo and doesn't make use of the Rails asset pipeline.

The stylesheet however, I'd like to have sprockets assemble from various sources as well as some values from the database.

Goals/desires:

- I'd like to start out with a stylesheet in app/assets/stylesheets
- I'd like the stylesheet in app/assets/stylesheets to include a base stylesheet that's distributed as part of the standalone RIA app found in public/ria/src/namespace/resources/base.styl
- I'd like to be able to run the stylesheet in app/assets/stylesheets through ERB to populate it with some variables based on the current tenant
- Ideally sprockets would cache the result of this process per-tenant

Important note:

- I bootstrap the application with a simple static HTML file in /public.  The RIA is in effect server agnostic and is a simple git module checked out into the public dir.